# Using -e option with sed to run sed from a script fails

Tags: sed

My sed command works fine on the command line but when I put it in a bash script and call it with

```
sed -e sedscript.sh
```

I get

```
$ sed -e sedscript.sh
sed: -e expression #1, char 12: unterminated `s' command
```

This is the sedscript.sh:

```
$cat sedscript.sh
sed 's/^ *[0-9]\+.//g' tictactoeold.py>tictactoenew.py
```

Comment: I believe the `-e` option is to add a `sed` script, not a shell script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-e` option of `sed` is to input a *valid* `sed` *expression*, not a file name containing `sed` commands, the `-f` option is for filename containing valid `sed` expressions.

In your case:

```
sed -e sedscript.sh
```

is being treaded as a substitution (`s`) operation of `sed` as the expression starts with `s`, with `e` as the delimiter for `s` (substitution), and `sed` is rightly complaining about the unterminated `s` (substitution) command.

Have fun:

```
% sed -e sedscript.sheFOOe <<<'dscript.shBAR'
FOOBAR
```

---

**What you can do:**

- Your file is necessarily a shell script, you can simple execute that as so
- Use `-e` to put the expession on the command line directly, `-e` is not strictly needed though:

  ```
   sed 's/^ *[0-9]\+.//g' tictactoeold.py >tictactoenew.py 

   sed -e 's/^ *[0-9]\+.//g' tictactoeold.py >tictactoenew.py
  ```
- Use the `-f` option, and just keep the `sed` expressions in the file only i.e. make the file `sedscript` as:

  ```
  s/^ *[0-9]\+.//g
  ```

  and then use the `sed` command as:

  ```
  sed -f sedscript tictactoeold.py >tictactoenew.py
  ```